# String.Replace not replacing the string during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, string

The following line in the below code doesn't cause any effect:

```
string1.Replace(string1.Substring(firstchar, lastchar - firstchar), "##");
```

`string1` remains unchanged and I get the same index returned when using IndexOf.

```
while (firstchar != string1.LastIndexOf("test"))
{

    firstchar = string1.IndexOf("test");
    lastchar = string1.IndexOf(" ");
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\textfile1.txt"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string1.Substring(firstchar, lastchar - firstchar));
        writer.WriteLine();
        writer.Dispose();
    }
    string1.Replace(string1.Substring(firstchar, lastchar - firstchar), "##");

}
```

Comment: Note that there's no point in explicitly calling `writer.Dispose()` at the end of a `using` statement which will dispose it already.

Answer (score 12):

Change

```
string1.Replace(string1.Substring(firstchar, lastchar - firstchar), "##");
```

to

```
string1 = string1.Replace(string1.Substring(firstchar, lastchar - firstchar), "##");
```

`string.Replace` does not alter the original string, but returns the altered string as it's return value.

Answer (score 7):

```
string1 = string1.Replace(...);
```

From the docs:
`String.Replace` ***returns*** a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutatble so if you change in a string object , a new object is created so you need to have the reference of the newly created string.

so

```
string1 = string1.Replace(string1.Substring(firstchar, lastchar - firstchar), "##");
```

will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Just as others said, you need to use the return value from the `replace` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you solve it by getting the value of "Replace".

I was doing the following:

```
string code = "A123BCD";
code.Replace("123", "R");
```

and expected to have "ARBCD", but it gave me the initial result.

But it was necessary to do:

```
code = code.Replace("123", "R");
```

and all good.